# Redis gets flushed mysteriously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I am running a rails app and using redis for jbulder's cache and sidekiq queue. I use sidekiq to send emails asyncly, everytime when I try to send mass emails, say 20k emails in background using sidekiq, after a while, all the background jobs in sidekiq queue are cleared, left 0 jobs in queue.

I filed an issue on sidekiq github page([link](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2119)), the author said it could be something or someone flushing my redis. There's no one flush redis manually and I wonder how can I find when and how redis gets flushed.

I've checked redis log file with nothing strange.

Comment: Did you tried to attach a MONITOR session to this Redis server so that you actually can check what happens?

Comment: Thanks! I should attach a monitor session.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://redis.io/topics/security#disabling-of-specific-commands) is the documentation on changing certain commands.  Perhaps consider changing `flushAll` and `flushDB` to something abnormal.